# How to use variadic template function correctly

Tags: c++, templates

I have some structs and an enum that look like this:

```
enum NUM
{
   A = 0,
   B,
   C
};

struct X{};
struct Y{};
```

I'd like to create a variadic template for a function that looks like this:

```
template<NUM n, typename...Args>
void func(const Args&...a);
```

I'd like to specialize the template function `func` in cases like this:

if `NUM::A` define `func` as

```
template<> void func<A, X>(const X& x)
{
   var.emplace_back(std::make_shared<SomeClass>(x));
}
```

if `NUM::B` define `func` as

```
template<> void func<B,X,Y>(const X& x, const Y& y)
{
   var.emplace_back(std::make_shared<SomeOtherClass>(x,y))
}
```

Could you help me tidy it up with variadic templates?

Comment: Partial specialisation of function templates is not allowed (or are `X` and `Y` concrete types?)

Comment: I think this belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Henri,
partial specialization ?
struct S
{
   template<class T>int GetT();
   template<> int GetT<Test>(){return sizeof(Test);}
};
Nothing's wrong with function specialization.

Comment: @OstrichGroomer What I'm saying is, that I don't understand your question (and most likely nobody else does either).

Comment: `Could you help me tidy it up with variadic templates?` Could you explain what do you mean by `tidy it up`? Your code works just fine as it is https://ideone.com/v9zP8H

Comment: What are you trying to do? What will the unspecialized template do? It seems somewhat implausible that there is no simpler solution to your actual problem.

Comment: @J.Doe This would be closed as off-topic on Code Review due to being example/stub code. It's not meaningfully reviewable in the form presented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial specialisation of functions can be achieved by deferring the implementation of the function to a function object template, which because it is a class template, can be partially specialised.

example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

enum NUM
{
   A = 0,
   B,
   C
};

struct X{};
struct Y{};

// guess at missing code in question

struct SomeBase
{
    virtual ~SomeBase() noexcept;
};

struct SomeClass : SomeBase
{
    SomeClass(const X&);
};

struct SomeOtherClass : SomeBase
{
    SomeOtherClass(const X&, const Y&);
};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeBase>> var;

// helper base class
struct func_impl_common
{
    func_impl_common(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeBase>>& var) : var(var) {}
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeBase>>& var;
};

// general template
template<NUM n, typename...Args> struct func_impl;

// now specialise for A X
template<> struct func_impl<A, X> : func_impl_common
{
    using func_impl_common::func_impl_common;
    void operator()(X const& x) const
    {
       var.push_back(std::make_shared<SomeClass>(x));
    }
};

// now specialise for B X Y
template<> struct func_impl<B, X, Y> : func_impl_common
{
    using func_impl_common::func_impl_common;
    void operator()(X const& x, Y const& y) const
    {
       var.push_back(std::make_shared<SomeOtherClass>(x, y));
    }
};

// define func in terms of function object template

template<NUM n, typename...Args>
void func(const Args&...a)
{
    auto op = func_impl<n, Args...>(var);
    op(a...);
}

// test

int main()
{
    func<A>(X{});
    func<B>(X{}, Y{});
}
```

However, if this is a real design it seems a little suspect.

Comment: Thank you, that is neat. I'm loving it a lot. ^^)). Please express your suspect if you would want to. lol

Comment: @OstrichGroomer Well, it seems to me that you already know whether you want a SomeClass or SomeOtherClass - because of the template argument A or B, which is not deduced, but rather it is explicitly stated. 
If you're going to explicitly state this template argument then you may as well have 2 functions: addSomeClass(x) and addSomeOtherClass(x, y).